# What is this if-statement called?

Tags: java, if-statement

So i was just wondering if there was actually a name for this if-statement:

```
public void checkEvenNumber(number) {
  return ((number % 2 == 0) ? true : false)
}
```

Or if it is just called an if-statement.

Comment: Do you mean ternary operator?

Comment: It's a ternary. How it works is `?` is what you choose to do if `true` is returned. `:` is if the condition is false. Just make a note this won't work since you're returning a boolean in a void method.

Comment: @mprabhat Just to be precise, this is not *the* ternary operator, but *a* ternary operator. It just happens that since Java doesn't have more ternary operators `condition ? option1 : option2` people tend to call it "ternary operator" instead of using its proper name which is "conditional operator".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes. That's an example of a [ternary operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F:#Java).

[JLS-15.25 Conditional Operator ? :](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.25) describes it as,

> The conditional operator `? :` uses the boolean value of one expression to decide which of two other expressions should be evaluated.

Answer (score 1):

It is called a `terniary operator`. However in this case, `terniary operator` isn't needed as the function it can be simplified to look like this:

```
public boolean isEvenNumber(int number) {
  return number % 2 == 0;
}
```

Please note that I changed the name of the function to match what it actually does.

Comment: What's odd is this returns true for even.

Comment: Ha, good call, updated.

Answer (score 0):

You may also refer it as `inline if statement`

Here's a link for your reading up: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F:

If you are familiar with how if-statements work in MS Excel, it shouldn't be too hard to understand.

---

By the way, your code should **change** to:

```
public void checkOddNumber(number) {
  return ((number % 2 != 0) ? true: false)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The ternary operator, so-called as it has 3 components:

1. The condition
2. The expression returned if it's true
3. The expression returned if it's false

Answer (score 0):

that's a function (as i recognize it), you pass parameter(s) to it and it is passes it/them down to the function (where you do your stuff) and it returns only 1 variable.